# Mongoose.js: Upsert + Type.Mixed

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, upsert

Is it possible to upsert a Type.Mixed data field? It doesn't seem to work, but I haven't stepped into the mongoose code yet.

Comment: What do you mean by upserting a data field?  Can you post what you've tried?

Comment: Further to JohnnyHK's comment .. you can upsert a *document*, but you should be [set()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-set)ing a field.